# '93 Cavalier ECU issue

Tags: chevrolet, electronic-control-module, cavalier

I have an old cavalier that loses power to the ECU randomly. It can take many attempts to start again. I do not lose battery power to the lights or stereo.

If I flick the keys to the on position repeatedly until the check engine light flashes, I can usually get it to start again.

This is what leads me to believe I am having power loss to the ECU. What confuses me is that it is so intermittent and has no apparent trigger. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's more than likely a ground fault you are seeing, but beyond that, I don't have any real advice for you.